# How to implement cross device notifications

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, notifications, cloud

I would like to implement a button in my app where if clicked I get a notification on my phone. Is this possible? Maybe with firebase integration. I'm using flutter and this would be really nice to implement. So it would basically be a prewritten message that will pop up on my phone (or in firebase would be enough if I get a notification)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to display notifications locally than you should go for flutter_local_notification otherwise you can use FCM using firebase_messaging

Comment: So I would like to display the notifications on my phone but the app user is on another phone. Like User 1 sees a button on the profile of User 2, this button has Hi written on it... If User 1 taps the 2nd User gets a notification with that text

Comment: You can use firebase_messaging. You need to store firebase tokens in firestore and use that token to send message to user2